# Joining threads confusion

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm doing my homework, what I have to accomplish is count the directories and files of a given directory, but each directory that I found should be counted aswell with another thread of my process, this is what I have so far:

```
void *dirCounter(void *param){
queue<pthread_t> queue;
dir_ptr dir = (dir_ptr)param;
dir->countDir = 0;
DIR* dirName = dir->name;
struct dirent *curr;
off_t dsp;
dsp= telldir(dirName);
while(dsp!= -1){
    curr = readdir(dirName);
    if(curr == NULL){
        break;
    }
    if(!strcmp(curr->d_name,".")|!strcmp(curr->d_name,"..")) {  //To avoid counting . and ..
        dsp = telldir(dirName); //Actual position asociated to the stream
        continue;   //Executes the beginning of the while
    }
    if(curr->d_type == DT_DIR){
        dir->countDir++; //counts directories in the first level
        //For each directory found, create another thread and add it to the queue:

        pthread_attr_t attr1;
        pthread_t tid1;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr1);
        dir_ptr par1 = (dir_ptr)malloc(sizeof(directorio));
        par1->name = opendir(curr->d_name);
        par1->countDir = par1->countFile = 0;
        pthread_create(&tid1,&attr1, dirCounter, par1);
        //queue.push(tid1);
    }
    if(curr->d_type == DT_REG){
        dir->countFile++; //Counts files
    }
    dsp = telldir(dirName);
}
//pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
//while(!queue.empty()){
    //pthread_join(queue.front(), NULL);
//  queue.pop();
//}
printf("Dirs: %d Files: %d\n", dir->countDir, dir->countFile);
pthread_exit(NULL); 
}
```

So far the code does count the current files and dirs of the "first level" if the join is commented, and then it just gives a segmentation fault, if the line is uncommented it gives just an output line and then dies with the segmentation fault.
The idea was to create a thread whenever I found a directory and then join all them at the end creating a semi-recursive routine.

Modifications:

```
char str[256];
strcpy(str, "./");
strcat(str, curr->d_name);
//strcat(str, "\"");
puts(str);
par1->name = opendir(str);
par1->countDir = par1->countFile = 0;
pthread_create(&tid1,&attr1, dirCounter, par1);
queue.push(tid1);
```

What it does after the modification:
Prints ALL the directories, however it does give segmentation fault and some threads do not complete it's task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proximate cause of your problem is that `dir->name` is `NULL` in the additional threads created, because `opendir(curr->d_name);` is failing.  This is because the directory `curr->d_name` is not an absolute pathname - `opendir()` will look in the *current working directory* for the directory you're trying to open, but that directory is actually within the directory you're currently working on.

I suggest that instead of passing the `DIR *` value to the thread, you instead simply pass the pathname of the directory, and let the thread do the `opendir()` itself.  It should then test the return value, and only proceed to call `readdir()` if `opendir()` returned non-NULL.

When you find a directory entry that is a directory, you need to construct a pathname to pass to the new thread by concatenating `"/"` and `curr->d_name` onto the pathname of the directory being processed.

Note that you do not need the `dsp` variable and the calls to `telldir()` at all.  If you have a valid `DIR *dir`, you can loop over it simply with:

```
while (curr = readdir(dir)) {
    /* Do something with curr */
}
```

Comment: very useful, however I could not make this modification, but I took the idea and made some changes in the code, which are now in my original post under the "Modifications" title :)

Answer (score 1):

I see a few bugs. I'm not sure if this explains your crash.

You allocated an instance of "directorio" for each directory and corresponding thread.  But you never free it.  Memory leak.

Is it the intent to print the total number of directories and files of the whole file system?  Or just a individual directory and file count for each directory?  If the former, you aren't adding the results back up. I would even suggest having all threads share the same integer pointers for dirCount and fileCount. (And use a lock to serialize access or just use [__sync_add_and_fetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)).  You could also just use a set of global variables for the integer dir and file counts.

If the latter case (each thread prints it's own summation of child files), just pass a directory name (string) as the thread parameter, and let the thread use local variables off the stack for the counters. (The thread would call opendir on the string passed in. It would still need to free the allocated string passed in.)

You don't need to pass a pthread_attr_t instance into pthread_create.  You can pass NULL as the second parameter and get the same effect.

You aren't checking the return value of pthread_create. If it were to fail (unlikely), then tid1 could be a garbage value.

Hope this helps.